# Load file into 2D char Array in C

Tags: c

I have a text file with 25 lines, each with 34 characters on.

In C how is it possible to load these characters and store them into a 2D array?

If the first three lines of the file are such:

```
bamaaaaaaaacxxxxxxxxxxbaaaaaaaamac
jzjzzzzzzzzdaaaaaaaaaaezzzzzzzzjzj
jzjzbaaczgzzzzzzzzzzzzzzgzbaaczjzj

...and so on
```

I require the array to be stored as if it was defined like this:

```
char* data[] = {
            "baaaaaaaaaaaaaacxxbaaaaaaaaaaaaaac",
            "jzzzzzzzzzzzzzzjxxjzzzzzzzzzzzzzzj",
            "jzbaaaaaaaaaaaaexxdaaaaaaaaaaaaczj",
...and so on
```

Hopefully this makes some sense! It is important that the type of `data` is `char data[][]` as it is used in that format in the rest of my project and cannot be changed.

I have done the basic begining of the File IO

```
FILE  *infp;

printf("Opening file\n");

if((infp = fopen("file.txt", "r"))== NULL) {
    printf("\nERROR : Unable to open input file\n");
    SetExitWithCode( 999 );
    }else{
            //code here
            }
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: your code is so not c++ (beside the way you open the file, everything else is a compilation error)

Comment: You should probably get a decent book on C and read the first few chapters before trying to write any more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want your array to look like this:

```
char data[25][35] //There is an extra 1 character per line to hold the null terminator character
```

Then simply read the whole file into that array

```
fread(data, 1, sizeof(data), infp);
```

And finally, replace the new line character in on each line with a terminator

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; ++i) {
    data[i][34] = 0;
}
```

This is the easiest solution to the problem, but it is also a bad way of doing it. It does not validate that the data is in the correct format, and everything is hard coded.

Comment: Fantastic! Sorry I should have mentioned that I have some #define values for these sizes! Many thanks!